# Pivot query causing "incorrect syntax" error in the PIVOT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am getting the error, "incorrect syntax near 'Basic'" when I try to execute the following query:

```
WITH BaseQuery AS (

SELECT Region,Essbase_Channel,Product,COUNT(New_reconnects)
FROM NDW.dbo.SOS_Detail SOS
WHERE SOS.EntityID IN ('000310','000700','000815','000854')
  AND Division ='NORTHEAST DIVISION' AND Month_Name ='MAR'
GROUP BY Month_Name,Product,Region,Essbase_Channel,EntityID,Division

)
SELECT * FROM BaseQuery

PIVOT (COUNT(New_reconnects) FOR Product IN ('BASIC','HSI','CDV','H1','X1')) AS PVT
ORDER BY Product,Region,Essbase_Channel
```

My goal would be to have the first column based on `Essbase_Channel`, the pivot columns to be `Product` values: BASIC, HSI, CDV, H1 and the values in the pivot to be `COUNT(New_reconnects)`.

How should I change the syntax of the query to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
FOR Product IN ([BASIC],[HSI],[CDV],[H1],[X1])
```